nvcc doesn't produce any windows output
The nvcc compiler doesn't produce any output whatsoever when it is called regularly.
Using --version gives me:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Apr_17_19:36:51_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.5, V12.5.40
Build cuda_12.5.r12.5/compiler.34177558_0

and using --verbose with anything as file path gives me:
 nvcc.exe --verbose anything
#$ C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat

C:\Users\n-sau>call "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/HostX64/x64/../../../../../../../VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.10.0
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
#$ ACSetupSvcPort=23210
#$ ACSvcPort=17532
#$ ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
#$ APPDATA=C:\Users\n-sau\AppData\Roaming
#$ cl=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx64\x64\x86
#$ cl.exe=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\Hostx86\x64
#$ CommandPromptType=Native
#$ CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
#$ CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
#$ CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
#$ COMPUTERNAME=NICOSCOMPUTER
#$ ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
#$ CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5
#$ CUDA_PATH_V12_5=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5
#$ DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
#$ DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
#$ EnableLog=INFO
#$ ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
#$ EXTERNAL_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
#$ Framework40Version=v4.0
#$ FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
#$ FrameworkDir64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
#$ FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
#$ FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
#$ FSHARPINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools
#$ HOMEDRIVE=C:
#$ HOMEPATH=\Users\n-sau
#$ INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
#$ LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64
#$ LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
#$ LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\n-sau\AppData\Local
#$ LOGONSERVER=\\NICOSCOMPUTER
#$ MSMPI_BENCHMARKS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Benchmarks\
#$ MSMPI_BIN=C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\
#$ MSMPI_INC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Include\
#$ MSMPI_LIB32=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x86\
#$ MSMPI_LIB64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\MPI\Lib\x64\
#$ NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
#$ NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=16
#$ nvvpDLL=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.3\extras\CUPTI\lib64
#$ OneDrive=C:\Users\n-sau\OneDrive
#$ OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\n-sau\OneDrive
#$ OPENSSL_ia32cap=:~0x20000000
#$ OS=Windows_NT
#$ Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2024.2.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2023.3.1\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\;C:\Users\n-sau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\n-sau\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build;;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
#$ PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
#$ Platform=x64
#$ PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
#$ PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 25 Model 33 Stepping 2, AuthenticAMD
#$ PROCESSOR_LEVEL=25
#$ PROCESSOR_REVISION=2102
#$ ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
#$ ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
#$ ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
#$ ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
#$ PROMPT=$P$G
#$ PSModulePath=C:\Users\n-sau\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
#$ PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
#$ RlsSvcPort=22112
#$ SESSIONNAME=Console
#$ SystemDrive=C:
#$ SystemRoot=C:\Windows
#$ UCRTVersion=10.0.22621.0
#$ UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
#$ USERDOMAIN=NICOSCOMPUTER
#$ USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=NICOSCOMPUTER
#$ USERNAME=n-sau
#$ USERPROFILE=C:\Users\n-sau
#$ VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
#$ VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\
#$ VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\
#$ VCPKG_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\vcpkg
#$ VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\
#$ VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.40.33807\
#$ VCToolsVersion=14.40.33807
#$ VisualStudioVersion=17.0
#$ VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\
#$ VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
#$ VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
#$ VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
#$ VSCMD_VER=17.10.0
#$ VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\
#$ windir=C:\Windows
#$ WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0
#$ WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
#$ WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
#$ WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.22621.0\
#$ WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\
#$ WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.22621.0\
#$ WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
#$ WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\
#$ WSLENV=WT_SESSION:WT_PROFILE_ID:
#$ WT_PROFILE_ID={61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}
#$ WT_SESSION=fdbf2f67-93a5-4cb3-a386-b2691e962efd
#$ __DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
#$ __DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
#$ __VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2024.2.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2023.3.1\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\java8path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\;C:\Users\n-sau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\n-sau\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.5\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build;

without any warning that anything isn't a file, or that soemthing else went wrong. The problem was raised at the nvidia developer forum
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvcc-not-doing-anything/112970/3
but didn't get any answer, worst part is, that I already got nvcc running in the past on the system, but then changed something regarding the cl.exe in path
I reinstalled cuda as well visual studio, without any success. I also tried using one of the dozen provided cl versions with the same result
(14.40.33807\bin\Hostx86\x86
14.40.33807\bin\Hostx86\x64
14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\x86
14.40.33807\bin\Hostx64\x64)
Trying to return any intermediate files during code generation also doesn't produce an output

this may be of interest

As Robert linked from the nvidia forum, deleting all my system paths except the base windows one and reinstalling Cuda and linking cl from visual studio worked
